# Как создать класс СSS с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, css

Есть файл js, в котором написан плагин, где используются CSS классы, к которым нет доступа. Как можно с помощью js добавить или изменить параметры этого класса?

```
card.addClass('card--collection');
```

Этот класс мне нужно изменить. Его значение `width`, которое прописано в СSS.

Answer (score 0):

Команда может выглядеть так:

```
card.setAttribute('class', 'card--collection')
```

Comment: Мне нудно для класса card--collection изменить свойства. Тоесть у него в CSS прописано width:19.1em; а мне нужно принудительно ему задать width:10.1em.

Comment: document.querySelector('.card--collection').style.width = '10.1em';

Comment: @СергейГуртовой инлайн стили переписывают свойства классов. Вы можете задать следующим способом: card.style.width = '10.1em'.

Comment: document.querySelector('.card--collection').style.width = '10.1em'; – 
Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style)

Comment: Быть может вы запускаете скрипт до прогрузки страницы? Я повторил код у себя, все работает

Comment: Это ответ не на тот вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Если очень нужно отредактировать сами правила, то можно работать с [CSSOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model) напрямую:

```js
function test() {
  const i = [...document.styleSheets[0].cssRules].findIndex(e => e.selectorText === ".card--collection")
  const myClassRule = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[i];
  myClassRule.style.width = "10.1em";
}
```

```css
.card--collection {
  height: 5em;
  width: 19.1em;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<p class="card--collection"></p>
<p class="card--collection"></p>
<button onclick="test()">test</button>
```

Comment: Немного не понял, а как оно поймет к какому именно классу обратиться?

Comment: Это уже работа с коллекциями - я привел упрощенный пример в ответе.